# yii2 DatePicker widget error

Tags: yii2, yii2-widget

Hello everyone I'm doing a form with dates , use the widget Kartik , but says

> Class ' kartik \ widgets \ DatePicker ' not found

Any suggestions? Thank you

**my code**

```html
use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;

 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => 'viaggio',
                    /*'enableAjaxValidation'   => true,
                    'enableClientValidation' => false,*/
                                 ]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'data_part')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter  ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true
    ]
]); ?>
```

Comment: can you  check this use kartik\date\DatePicker;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, **error** says.

> Class ' kartik \ widgets \ DatePicker ' not found

Change

```
use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;
```

To

```
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
```

**Updated Code:**

```
use kartik\date\DatePicker;

 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => 'viaggio',
                    /*'enableAjaxValidation'   => true,
                    'enableClientValidation' => false,*/
                    ]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'data_part')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter  ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true
    ]
]); ?>
```

See **Usage** section of [Kartik yii2-widget-datepicker](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker)

Comment: *Happy Coding* @Saba